# Como apontar através do Login, qual banco de dados o sistema deve se conectar via Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, java-ee

Estou desenvolvendo um sistema JAVA com JSF, PrimeFaces e Hibernate com banco de dados Mysql. 
Neste sistema o usuário deverá informar no login o banco que deseja se conectar  (Usuário, senha e banco). 
O problema é que quando o usuário chama a tela de Login o Hibernate ja inicia a fabrica de sessões antes do usuário informar os dados de conexão.
Gostaria de saber se tem um jeito de o Hibernate só iniciar a fabrica de sessões após o usuário clicar em Logar.

Comment: Você tem várias bases de dados já criadas? E o usuário deve logar nas bases ou utilizar os dados delas para logar no sistema?

Comment: Eu tenho varias bases. No Login a pessoa informa, usuário, senha e a base que deseja se logar. Com base nestas informações o sistema deverá se conectar na base apontada para realização de apontamentos.

Comment: Como você ta declarando suas fábricas de conexões..? Pode ser que do modo que esteja , ela inicie automaticamente com o sistema.. aqui tem uma forma de iniciá-la programaticamente.. com isso você pode iniciar a que desejar..

http://allandequeiroz.io/2017/02/05/creating-jpa-entity-manager-programmatically-with-hibernate-and-cdi/

Comment: Vou tentar postar o código.

Answer (score 0):

```
    private static SessionFactory criarFabricaDeSessoes(String nomeDoArquivo) {
    try {
        Configuration configuracao = new Configuration().configure(nomeDoArquivo);

        ServiceRegistry registro = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(configuracao.getProperties())
                .build();

        SessionFactory fabrica = configuracao.buildSessionFactory(registro);

        return fabrica;
    } catch (Throwable ex) {
        System.err.println("A fábrica de sessões não pode ser criada." + ex);
        throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
    }
}
```